# Driving on stones

Tags: ford

I recently ended up on a dirt track while accesing a nature reserve and it was fairly flat butcovered in stones. There was no way back so had to keep going for about 5 kilometres over the stony track. I could hear stones hitting the car (don't know if the sides or the underneath). I'm worried I might have damaged something I can't see. The car appears to be unharmed as it drives perfectly well, as it did before, but I'm a bit paranoid about unseen damage. Any advice? My car is a 2018 Ford Ka+
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

New cars are made to take some abuse - as long as you weren't flying down the road at highway speeds, and as long as you didn't go over large bumps that caused the bottom of the car to scrape the ground, you shouldn't have any issues. Especially in a front wheel drive car, which doesn't really have anything to be damaged once you get past the front axle.

If you're really concerned, you can have a shop put the car in the air and inspect for any damage, but I think the worst thing they'll find is some pebbles collected wherever they could find a spot.

You might want to kick the bottom of the rear bumper and side skirts to free any stuck pebbles (so they don't fall out once you're back on the road and pepper someone elses car). But assuming the car isn't making any new noises since your offroading excursion, you should be fine c:

Answer (score 0):

A pebble coming your car and especially if stuck on the wheels, can break someone else windshield. it is a common occurence in African dirt roads.

Comment: I doubt this is still an issue.  All the pebbles are gone, and all the windshields are broken... four years ago.